# How can I make only the second heading level numbered in markdown?

Tags: markdown, wiki

```
<<toc>>

# heading lvl 1

## heading lvl 2
## heading lvl 2
## heading lvl 2
```

Hi want this lvl 2 numbered. But not as a numered list because this wouldn't appear in the toc. It should be a heading because I need it in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown doesn't support this natively (nor does it support `<<toc>>`).

You might be able to find some third-party Markdown processors that offer more flexibility, but to do what you want with regular Markdown your only option is to number your headings manually:

```
# heading lvl 1

## 1. heading lvl 2
## 2. heading lvl 2
## 3. heading lvl 2
```

Of course, if the wiki you hint at (but don't specify) automatically numbers headlines you may be out of luck since there is no Markdown syntax to remove numbering.